# Problems pushing to Github "Authentication failed"

Tags: git, github

I'm a newbie and maybe that's a dumb problem but when I'm trying to push my portfolio to github I'm getting **"fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/username/Portfolio.git'** I've googled the question and it led me here but people were talking about tokens and stuff that I don't understand. Any help or guidance will be very appreciated.

Comment: If the answer is working , you probably should mark it as "Solved" (the tick) for anyone having same issue. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+PAT+password

Answer (score 3):

I see your problem is trying to push to Github via HTTPS. Your error is usually caused by the authentication error while authenticating using a username and password.

> Beginning August 13, 2021, we will no longer accept account passwords when authenticating Git operations on GitHub.com.

To solve your problem, I suggest you create a personal access token as described here: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Once you generate your personal access token, you can use it as a password. Personal access token only shows once, so keep it in a safe place and you can use it again in the future.

But you can also save it as a cache, so Github won't ask you to authenticate every time you clone, push, pull, etc by running this code before doing Github commands:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

Answer (score 0):

Github is using SSH keys to identify you and your machine.

Generating GitHub SSH Keys

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@youremail.com"
```

[image]

This will generate new id_rsa and id_rsa.pub keys in your ~/.ssh/ directory. (You need to locate your id_rsa.pub and get the key using any text editor)

To upload this newly created key to GitHub, go to:

Account Settings
[image]
SSH Keys
Add SSH Key
Paste your key where applicable - cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub or Notepad in windows to get the contents.
[image]
Add Key
Connect

For more information you can follow [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)

Comment: The OP uses HTTPS, not SSH.

Comment: I already have an access token on GitHub but I'm still getting the error message. How to resolve that?